# How could i use explode effect with a sprite in libgdx..?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

i am trying to develop a game in libgdx in which i want to use explode effect with sprite when i clicked on it. is it possible or i should use BOX2D physics to apply the explode effect.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the API that handles Animations for you, or if you want to use particles you must use the API that provides Emmiters for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing explosion effects on my own. For every particle object I have variables that hold X and Y coords and in VX and VY I'm holding particle speed.

When explosion happens I'm creating some number of those objects (I'm storing them in a list). For every one of those particles I set X and Y coords with the coords of explosion it self. So they all start at same point. But for every particle I set different, random VX and VY (initial speed). So they will start moving in different directions.

I'm also implementing some gravity effect - in every frame I'm decreasing VY for some constant (multiplied with that delta time - time since last frame rendering, to get constant moving).

At end you should check somehow when to remove particle object. I.e. when it's coordinates are out of screen or after some time or something...

To make it even nice you can animate particles...use transparency...

Answer (score 0):

One simple way you can achieve what you wanted is through the use of particles

I am guessing that your game is 2d so [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2d-particle-effects) is the official wiki about 2d particles

Answer (score 0):

As MilanG stated the easiest way ist to create a Particle class

```
public class Particle{
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float vx;
    public float vy;

    public Particle(float x, float y, float vx, float vy){...}
}
```

Then when the user clicks on the Texture you would instantiate a lot of these particles and add them to an ArrayList. X and Y coordinates should be the center of your texture. vx can be a random number (negative and positive). vy can also be a random number depending on the visual effect of your particles. Experiment with the values a bit

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    arrayList.add(new Particle(textureX,
                               textureY,
                               MathUtils.randomFloat(-200, 200),
                               MathUtils.randomFloat(0, 200)));
}
```

In the update loop you would change the x and y coordinates according to vx and vy values. The vy value should be decrased because of gravity:

```
for(Particle p : arrayList){
    p.x += p.vx * delta;
    p.y += p.vy * delta;
    p.vy += -200 * delta; // -200 is gravity value
}
```

In you render code you draw the particle texture for every element in the arraylist:

```
for(Particle p : arrayList){
    batch.draw(particleTexture, p.x, p.y);
}
```

**Important:**
You also need to implement some logic to remove particles from the arrayList (like checking for x and y coordinate boundings together with a CopyOnWriteArrayList or a second deleteParticles ArrayList)

**Important as well:**
Another point to mention is that this technique generates a lot of objects causing a heavy GC to follow. You can reduce that by using a Pooling technique. LibGDX has some pretty nice classes for that.